# Return address x86 Assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86

I get the code above but the questions is why there's return value at ebp+4 ? I simply call a function and set the new EBP but i don't see an explicitly push of any return adress . Any tips ?

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
```

Comment: `call` itself pushes a return address.

Comment: Try using a debugger to see what instructions affect the stack regarding a function call.